# Why is Apache not proxying to Tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat9

Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 9 are installed on the same Ubuntu 20.04 server.  I'm trying to set up Apache as a reverse proxy to Tomcat.  This configuration is already working perfectly on an Apache 2.4/Tomcat 7/Ubuntu 16.04 system, but I'm having trouble transferring it to the new server.

`mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_ajp` are enabled on Apache.  The Proxy/ReverseProxy directives are contained in a site config file `mysite.conf`, and they're identical to the directives on the older, functioning system.

By itself, Apache works.  If I substitute the default site config for `mysite.conf`, I successfully get the Ubuntu Apache2 default page.

In Tomcat's `server.xml` file, I've uncommented the AJP connector and edited it slightly:

```
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443"
               enableLookups="false"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

This is also identical to the config on the older, functioning system.

By itself, Tomcat works.  If I access the server specifying port 8080, I get the webapp that it's serving.  The error is somewhere in the Apache/Tomcat connection.

When I attempt to connect via Apache (i.e., with `mysite.conf` enabled), the connection results in a 503 "Service Unavailable" error from Apache.  These lines appear in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file:

```
[Fri Mar 26 13:33:12.507582 2021] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 349130] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
[Fri Mar 26 13:33:12.507633 2021] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 349130] [client 10.11.12.13:53812] AH00992: ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Fri Mar 26 13:33:12.507643 2021] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 349130] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.11.12.13:53812] AH00878: read response failed from 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost)
```

I searched for these errors, but the only suggestions I could find (setting `ProxyTimeout 600` in Apache's `mysite.conf`, for example) did not have any effect on the problem.

Am I missing something?  How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. The `redirectPort="8443"` attribute for the AJP connector in Tomcat's `server.xml` is for SSL connections.  Since I'm still working on the basic connection, I haven't enabled SSL yet, so this should be `redirectPort="8080"`
2. Between the two versions of Tomcat that I'm using, the attribute `secretRequired` for the AJP connector was changed from a default of `false` to a default of `true`.  Since I wasn't sending a password with the proxy connection, it failed.  I discovered this when I finally remembered to check the Tomcat logs, too (`/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.{date}.log` on Ubuntu).

The following AJP config works and allows me to load the webapp reverse-proxied through Apache:

```xml
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8080"
           enableLookups="false"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           secretRequired="false" />
```

Comment: `redirectPort` should only point to an SSL port. Until then you can disable the redirect using `redirectPort="0"`.

Comment: I can confirm that `redirectPort="0"` also works.